# can't look up key value using value from array

Tags: javascript

I'm coding a game with 100 tiles that are generated like this:

```js
const allLetters = {
  'A': { 'points':  1, 'tiles':  9 },
  'B': { 'points':  3, 'tiles':  2 },
  'C': { 'points':  3, 'tiles':  2 },
  'D': { 'points':  2, 'tiles':  4 },
  'E': { 'points':  1, 'tiles': 12 },
  'F': { 'points':  4, 'tiles':  2 },
  'G': { 'points':  2, 'tiles':  3 },
  'H': { 'points':  4, 'tiles':  2 },
  'I': { 'points':  1, 'tiles':  9 },
  'J': { 'points':  8, 'tiles':  1 },
  'K': { 'points':  5, 'tiles':  1 },
  'L': { 'points':  1, 'tiles':  4 },
  'M': { 'points':  3, 'tiles':  2 },
  'N': { 'points':  1, 'tiles':  6 },
  'O': { 'points':  1, 'tiles':  8 },
  'P': { 'points':  3, 'tiles':  2 },
  'Q': { 'points': 10, 'tiles':  1 },
  'R': { 'points':  1, 'tiles':  6 },
  'S': { 'points':  1, 'tiles':  4 },
  'T': { 'points':  1, 'tiles':  6 },
  'U': { 'points':  1, 'tiles':  4 },
  'V': { 'points':  4, 'tiles':  2 },
  'W': { 'points':  4, 'tiles':  2 },
  'X': { 'points':  8, 'tiles':  1 },
  'Y': { 'points':  4, 'tiles':  2 },
  'Z': { 'points': 10, 'tiles':  1 },
  ' ': { 'tiles': 2 }
}

let tiles = [];

Object.keys(allLetters).forEach(letter => {
  for (let i = 0; i < allLetters[letter]['tiles']; i += 1){
    tiles.push(letter);
  }
});

console.log(tiles);
```

I want to associate each tile with a point value, so this is what I tried:

```
var playersTiles = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 7; i++){
  let tileIndex = Math.round(Math.random() * (tiles.length - 1));
  playersTiles.push(tiles[tileIndex]);
  let letter = playersTiles[i];
  let points = allLetters[letter]['points'];
  playersTiles.push(tiles[tileIndex][points]);
  tiles.splice(tileIndex, 1);
}
```

My code returns an error on this line:

```
let points = allLetters[letter]['points'];
```

It says:

```
allLetters[letter] is undefined
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are pushing onto playersTiles twice in each iteration of the loop. The first one adds a letter, and the second one tries to add a points value, but you aren't accessing points correctly. tiles[tileIndex][points] is always undefined because tiles is just a list of letters

Comment: Why not collect the value when you run over `allLetters` loop => `tiles.push({letter : letter, point : allLetters[letter]['points']});` or `tiles.push([letter, allLetters[letter]['points']]);`

Answer (score 0):

That's because `tiles` is a one dimensional array shown in your code here

```
let tiles = [];

Object.keys(allLetters).forEach(letter => {
    for (let i = 0; i < allLetters[letter]['tiles']; i += 1){
        tiles.push(letter); // Pushing only the letter which makes it one-dimensional array
    }
});
```

And in this part `playersTiles.push(tiles[tileIndex][points]);` you are assuming that `tiles` is a two-dimensional array

Comment: But my code errors out before `playersTiles.push(tiles[tileIndex][points]);` even comes up. It errors out on the previous line.